# Program expecting".class", and no explanation

Tags: java

I know this code may be simple to a few of you guys, but I'm a struggling sophomore in an AP class. My problem is that the program is expecting ".class"  before the "%".

```
public void run()
    {
        int[] oddIndexArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    }

    public void printOddIndices(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

            if(int[] % 2 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `arr [i]` is what  you need

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to make your if statement like this

```
if(arr[i] % 2 != 0)
```

You need the variable name (`arr`, not`int[]`) and you need to pass the array index (`arr[i]`)

Comment: Thanks, not really sure how i missed that haha.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if statement as follows

```
 if( arr[i] % 2 != 0)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: @JohnGalt, if it solves your problem please accept the answer